# Amd RX 500 series compatibility with linux (drivers issues)

Tags: 16.04, drivers, 18.04, amd-graphics

I recently bought an RX 570 card and it seems that one way or another you cannot use it properly on linux. Currently running Ubuntu 16.04 and there are two possible driver setups:

The proprietary amdgpu-pro driver does not support EGL (while the driver is advertising it) thus all apps (i.e. kodi) using EGL crash. https://community.amd.com/thread/213078

The open source driver does not enable audio over the hdmi connection.

Is there any solution or should I replace the card with an Nvidia one?

Comment: Nvidia usually has better Linux support, so, yes, replace it.

Answer (score 0):

The open source amdgpu driver solves both the EGL crash and the audio over the hdmi.